# Session variable not working

Tags: php, forms, session

I am using one session variable in my php page. As per my infomation, it is accessible throughout the program and it is, but problem is that it is showing different value for the same variable at different place in php page?

the code is as follows

```
<html><body>

<?php session_start(); 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['x']))
     $_SESSION['x']=1;  

echo "X=". $_SESSION['x']; 

?>
<form>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['save']))
{  
  if(isset($_SESSION['x']))
      $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x']+1;
   echo $_SESSION['x']."<br>";  
}
else
  echo "no submit";
?>
</body></html>
```

value becomes different before and after submit button click? Please tell me why it is so?
thanks in advavnce.

Comment: Where is your <form> method defined ?

Comment: What values does it give you/? What values are you expecting? also, do this: `<form method="get" /> and set it an action if you want it to work!

Answer (score 0):

it is due to the code itself

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['x'])) //It is set
      $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x']+1; //Add 1 to the value
echo $_SESSION['x']."<br>";  return value with +1
```

**Solution**

The reason the output is different is the order you echo and update

```
//Echo
//Update Value
//Echo again
```

Simple solution would be to move this

```
if (isset($_GET['save']))
{  
  if(isset($_SESSION['x']))
      $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x']+1;
   echo $_SESSION['x']."<br>";  
}
else
  echo "no submit";
```

to above this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['x']))
     $_SESSION['x']=1;  

echo "X=". $_SESSION['x'];
```

Also note set the method and the action in the form to make sure it calls itself

```
<form method="GET" action="[url to itself]">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the solution? Isn't this what OP has?

Comment: Sir, i have initialized the value of session variable just after session_start(). The default form method is get. So, i did not mentioned it. when the php page loads it shows the default set value "1". but when i click in submit button, it shows the increment value as "2" only when i echoed it in if(isset()) block i.e. first echo print 1 and second echo print 2. but i want to have the same value at both. How to do this.

Comment: @user2931596 if it helps please be so kind as to mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
<html><body>

<?php session_start(); 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['x']))
 $_SESSION['x']=1;  

echo "X=". $_SESSION['x']; 

?>
<form method="GET" action="">
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
</form>
<?php
 if (isset($_GET['save']))
 {  
 if(isset($_SESSION['x']))
   echo $_SESSION['x']."<br>";
 }
 else
 echo "no submit";
?>
</body></html>
```

this way the code prints out the same value after submit as it did before.
Either way you try if you print value and change after or change value and print after, when page reloads it will change value. you could add another button called increment and add the following code inside the php :

```
if (isset($_GET['inc']))
{  
  if(isset($_SESSION['x']))
      $_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x']+1; 
}
```

and this one inside the form:

```
<input type="submit" name="inc" value="inc" />
```

this way youre variable increment when you press the inc button

Answer (score 0):

You are redeclaring the value of session variable 'x' here

```
$_SESSION['x'] = $_SESSION['x']+1;
```

This is why its appearing 1 greater than its initial value.

Comment: Please tell me the way to get same value at both echo statement.